# Ask logged in user to re-enter password to access page "x"

Tags: password, user-access

For security reasons, I want to request logged in users to re-enter their passwords to access certain pages on my the site.

How can I accomplish this?
I'm using Wordpress 4.4

Comment: Please explain better if you can. The whole point of making user to login for the whole site is to avoid having them to login to every page they read. How is a login at a specific page is different then the general login?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get user's hash *(hash is encrypted password)* from the database:

```
get_currentuserinfo();

$user_hash = $current_user->user_pass_md5;
```

---

Then check if it's correct:

```
wp_check_password( $password, $user_hash, $user_id );
```

`$password` - Plaintext user's password from input

`$user_hash` - Encrypted password from database

`$user_id` - user ID I guess

---

But as Mark said in comment - this is **extremely bad idea**. User has already logged in and entered his/her password. Have you ever had to instert your password multiple times in here? Facebook? Gmail? No, because it's not a good idea. Even banks don't do it unless your session times out.